# Where is the "Burial Wishes" Act 4 lore book?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

I've been through the Act many times and have not seen this drop. Where is it?

[image: Burial Wishes]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's actually in the **Act IV hub** (Bastion's keep stronghold), north of the waypoint [at least during quest 1]. It's on the corpse of **Martha**.

You can go there by using the portal (Click on T) It is rather easy to miss actually.

[Screenshot](http://s811.photobucket.com/user/of_adam/media/aa/Screenshot001.jpg.html)

Comment: I just tried this and it looks like the book does go away after the first quest.

Comment: I've looked extensively in the areas mentioned. A screenshot would be great, if possible.
I can't see her corpse and I just started the quest again, to ensure it should be there, to no avail.
Further assistance would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Make sure you're at the very beginning of Act 4. TP to town before talking to Tyrael. Left to the blacksmith directly in front of the (now closed) gates there's a corpse. [Here's](http://s811.photobucket.com/user/of_adam/media/aa/Screenshot001.jpg.html) a screenshot and [here's](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3Fh58nAMOA) a video on YouTube.

Answer (score 5):

1. Start the first quest of Act 4 (any difficulty)
2. Teleport to town
3. Go to the north-east end of town, where the gates lead to outside
4. The corpse laying on the ground by the exit (still in town) contains 
   "BURIAL WISHES"